# Combining separate self.request.sessions into one request

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to optimize and reduce some of my code, and just generally understand it better as this is my first development project.

The below works fine but is it possible to simplify it?

```
self.request.session['path_one_images'] = PATH_ONE_IMAGES                   
self.request.session['images'] = images
self.request.session['slider_DV_values'] = slider_DV_values
self.request.session['instruction_task_one_images'] = INSTRUCTION_TASK_ONE_IMAGES
self.request.session['instruction_task_two_images'] = INSTRUCTION_TASK_TWO_IMAGES
```

I tried to combine the separate requests in one using a dict but get the error:

> Exception Value:  unhashable type: 'list'

```
self.request.session({['path_one_images'] : PATH_ONE_IMAGES,                   
                      ['images'] : images,
                      ['slider_DV_values'] : slider_DV_values,
                      ['instruction_task_one_images'] : INSTRUCTION_TASK_ONE_IMAGES,
                      ['instruction_task_two_images'] : INSTRUCTION_TASK_TWO_IMAGES,})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.session` is a basically a Python mapping just like a dictionary, and it supports all dictionary methods. Like [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) to set multiple key-value pairs:

```
self.request.session.update({
    'path_one_images': PATH_ONE_IMAGES,                   
    'images': images,
    'slider_DV_values': slider_DV_values,
    'instruction_task_one_images': INSTRUCTION_TASK_ONE_IMAGES,
    'instruction_task_two_images': INSTRUCTION_TASK_TWO_IMAGES
})
```

Note that the keys are *not lists*; you were getting confused by the `object[...]` subscription syntax there.

Answer (score 1):

you know this is wrong syntax for a dict, yes?
`{['path_one_images'] : PATH_ONE_IMAGES}`

...should be
`{'path_one_images': PATH_ONE_IMAGES, etc}`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

this explains the error you're getting ("unhashable type: 'list'")... Python thinks you're trying to use a list `['path_one_images']` as the dict key. Dict keys don't have to be strings but they have to be *[hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)*. In this case you just want to use the string `'path_one_images'`.

Then additionally, as @Martijn Pieters pointed out, the session dict itself isn't callable, you should use the `update` method, eg:

```
self.request.session.update({
    'path_one_images': PATH_ONE_IMAGES,                   
    'images': images,
    'slider_DV_values': slider_DV_values,
    'instruction_task_one_images': INSTRUCTION_TASK_ONE_IMAGES,
    'instruction_task_two_images': INSTRUCTION_TASK_TWO_IMAGES
})
```

Comment: But the session object *isn't callable*.

Comment: @Anentropoc I should have said that i tried that but got the error `Exception Value:  

'SessionStore' object is not callable`